# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}(k,a)\equiv0\pmod{a-1}\iff a $ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Denote $\gcd(a,b)$ as $(a,b)$

Let $a\ge 2$, can it be shown that

$$(1,a)+(2,a)+\cdots+(a-1,a)\equiv0\pmod{a-1}$$

Satisfy if and only if $a$ is prime?

Clearly if $a$ is prime then $(1,a)+(2,a)+\cdots+(a-1,a)\equiv1+1+\cdots +1\equiv a-1\equiv0\pmod{a-1}$

Claim's hold true upto $10^4$ source code Pari GP

```
forcomposite(a=2,10000,if(sum(k=1,a-1,gcd(k,a))%(a-1)==0,print([a])))
```

Update #1

Sequence1 for composite $a$,  $[a,\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}(k,a)\equiv\pmod{a-1}]$

```
[4, 1][6, 4][8, 5][9, 4][10, 8][12, 6][14, 12][15, 2][16, 2][18, 11][20, 14][21, 4][22, 20][24, 7][25, 16][26, 24][27, 2][28, 22][30, 18][32, 18][33, 8][34, 32][35, 14][36, 27][38, 36][39, 10][40, 23][42, 30][44, 38][45, 12][46, 44][48, 4][49, 36][50, 47][51, 14][52, 46][54, 30][55, 26][56, 39][57, 16][58, 56][60, 5][62, 60][63, 24][64, 3][65, 32][66, 54][68, 62][69, 20][70, 5][72, 64][74, 72][75, 28][76, 70][77, 44][78, 66][80, 36][81, 56][82, 80][84, 21][85, 44][86, 84][87, 26][88, 71][90, 32][91, 54][92, 86][93, 28][94, 92][95, 50][96, 84][98, 10][99, 48][100, 24]
```

---

Edit: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/393216/149083) for MO post which asks for such infinitely many composite number.

Comment: The smallest counterexample is $41124$.

Comment: @Vepir surprising, thanks, you may put it as ans too

Comment: Btw, the following modification of your conjecture $$\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}(k,a)\equiv a-1\pmod{a}\iff a \text{ prime,}$$ appears to have no small counterexamples. (See comments in [A018804](https://oeis.org/A018804): "*Conjecture: n>1 divides a(n)+1 iff n is prime. - Thomas Ordowski, Oct 22 2014*".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to $10^8$, there are $4$ counterexamples: $41124, 230867, 358267, 37539572$.

This was possible thanks to [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4033952/318073), where they write a formula for $f(a)$.

I obtained counterexamples by running the formula in PARI/GP:

```
forcomposite(a=2,10^8,s=0;fordiv(a,d,s+=d*eulerphi(a/d));if(s%(a-1)==1,print([a])))
```

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

Adding $a$ to both sides means you can define:

$$f(a) =\sum_{k=1}^a (k,a)\tag 1$$

And you want $f(a)\equiv 1\pmod{a-1}\iff a$ is prime.

Then show that:

$$f(a)=\sum_{d\mid a} d\phi(a/d)$$

Thus $f$ is multiplicative.

So then compute $f(p^n)=np^{n-1}(p-1)+p^n$, when $p$ is prime.

So that gives you a general formula for $f(a)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $a.$

But I don’t see where to go from there. I’m not even sure there isn’t a counterexample.